# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool'

Tags: arrays, swift, string, closures

I am struggling with the syntax for checking an array to see if it contains a string. I am checking a string array using contains function. But get an error noted, and I can't work out the syntax for the closure. Can anyone help?

```
var connectedPeripherals = [String]()

if let connectedPeripherals = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "ConnectedPeripherals") {
    if connectedPeripherals.contains(where: (peripheral.identifier.uuidString)) {
     // Gives error: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool'"
     manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use UserDefaults method `stringArray(forKey:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416414-stringarray which returns an array of strings `[String]`. Btw using `if let connectedPeripherals = ...` won't assign any value to the variable you've declared out of the conditional closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `contains(where:)` expects a `closure` as parameter, you are passing a `String`.

So to fix your code it should be:

```
var connectedPeripherals = [String]()

if let connectedPeripherals = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "ConnectedPeripherals") as? String {
    if connectedPeripherals.contains(where: { $0 == peripheral.identifier.uuidString }) {
        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thx Otavio, that was surely one of the variations I tried, but you nailed it!

Comment: hi - i thought that fixed it, but actually that gives an error "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'String'"

Comment: @richc Fixed, it should work for your case without problems now.
OOPer's answer is a good one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- The return type of [`array(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414792-array) is `[Any]?`, its Element type `Any` is useless for almost all operations. You should better cast it to an appropriate type when you know the actual Element type.
- The method name `contains` has many overloads, you may want to call [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2904924-contains), not [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains).

Try this:

```
if let connectedPeripherals = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "ConnectedPeripherals") as? [String] {
    if connectedPeripherals.contains(peripheral.identifier.uuidString) {
        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Or, as suggested by Leo Dabus, this may be better:

```
if let connectedPeripherals = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "ConnectedPeripherals") {
    if connectedPeripherals.contains(peripheral.identifier.uuidString) {
        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416414-stringarray